# Read one character at a time from istream input

Tags: c++, insert, overloading

This code is supposed to store a very long user typed number using a custom data structure (type of stack) as a substitute to arrays or STL containers. I'm trying to overload >> operator so that

```
LongInt int1;
cin>>int1;
```

will work.

My code:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& input, LongInt& number) //class name is LongInt
{
    char c;
    int a;
    while (input>>c){ // read one number at a time
        a=c-'0'; // converting the value to int
        number.stackli.push(a); // pushing the int to the custom stack
    }

    return input;
}
```

should terminate after the user typed his number and pressed enter, but instead results in an infinite loop. Commenting out the two lines inside the loop still results in an infinite loop. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample input and an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "should terminate after the user typed his number and pressed enter" - where is that expectation expressed in your code?  (hint - it's not)  `input >> c` returns true until you have some error on the stream or hit end-of-file....

Comment: why not use input.get(c)

Comment: @Bot Is `input.get(c)` any different than `input >> c`?

Comment: input.get(c) by itself results in a segmentation error. Putting it inside the while loop still results in an infinite loop. @Tony D, what do you mean by expectation that it will end? I thought that the /n produced by pressing enter takes care of that

Comment: @abd: not at all... '\n' in the input stream will be skipped by default when using `input >> c` (there's a `skipws` mode on streams by default); for example, inputs of "12 34\n\t56" and "123456" work the same way for your code.  You're better off either using `input.peek()` to check you're not at EOF and have a digit, then `get` it, or just use `get()` and `unget()` any non-digit, carefully setting failed state if there are no digits at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because `(input >> c)` will always be `true` as long as `input` is in `good` state, say, not closed, hence the infinite loop.

Even you don't have anything input, the loop is "blocked" instead of "ended".

To consume just a part from the input stream instead of whole, you'll need something like:

```
while(input >> c) {
    if(c<='0' || c>='9') {
        // "c" is not the character you want, put it back and the loop ends
        input.putback(c); break;
    }
    ...
}
```